# 3 column layout but 1 under the 2

Tags: html, css

How would i do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BxaNN/369/
but with the top column in the center top?
NOTE: this is not my code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div id="content" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-sm-12 ">
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-lg-4  col-sm-6 col-lg-pull-4">
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-right" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you got the example how it should look like, why not inspect it using the developer tools to understand how they did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap classes you have already does this for you. You just need to reference the bootstrap cdn. You could also, center the text to make it pretty. check out the grid system here: [Bootstrap Resource](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```css
.container {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div id="content" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-sm-12 ">
<h2>1</h2>
<p>1</p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-lg-4  col-sm-6 col-lg-pull-4">
<h2>2</h2>
<p>2</p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-right" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
<h2>3</h2>
<p>4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```